# How to iterate on mongoose subdocument array of objects

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, subdocument

Trying to implement conditional statement relying on subdocument array of objects, so i need to iterate over collection of users in database and check inside each user subdocument array of objects with findIndex as for javascript

Users collection

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true,
    lowercase: true
  }
  friends: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User"
    }
  ],
  family: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User"
    }
  ],
  acquaintances: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User"
    }
  ],
  following: [
    {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: "User"
    }
  ],
  pendingFriendConfirmationData:[
    {
      storedUserId : {type: String},
      choosenCategories: [{label: {type: String}, value: {type: String}}]
    }
  ]
});

const Users = mongoose.model("Users", userSchema);
module.exports = Users;
```

now i can access Users collection with

```
db.Users.find()
```

my example result for

```
let filter = {"_id": userId}
let projection = {username: 1, friends: 1, family: 1, acquaintances: 1, following: 1, pendingFriendConfirmationData: 1}

db.Users.findOne(filter, projection, (err, user)=>{
      console.log(user)
    })
```

```
{
   friends: [],
   family: [],
   acquaintances: [],
   following: [],
   _id: 5ca1a43ac5298f8139b1528c,
   username: 'ahmedyounes',
   pendingFriendConfirmationData: [
     {
       choosenCategories: [Array],
       _id: 5ccb0fcf81a7944faf819883,
       storedUserId: '5cc95d674384e302c9b446e8'
     }
   ]
 }
```

focusing on pendingFriendConfirmationData 
the following screenshot from MongoDB Compass

[image]

I want to iterate over like this

```
let filter = {"_id": userId}
let projection = {username: 1, friends: 1, family: 1, acquaintances: 1, following: 1, pendingFriendConfirmationData: 1}

db.Users.findOne(filter, projection, (err, user)=>{
      let data = user.pendingFriendConfirmationData
      for(let i in data){
       if(data[i].choosenCategories.findIndex(v => v.label === "friend") !== -1){
        console.log("he is a friend")
      }
      }
    })
```

How to iterate over pendingFriendConfirmationData and choosenCategories 
like above

for now if i console.log(data) as following

```
db.Users.findOne(filter, projection, (err, user)=>{
      let data = user.pendingFriendConfirmationData
      console.log(data)
    })
```

**I get**

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out [Faster Mongoose Queries With Lean](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/lean.html)

The lean option tells Mongoose to skip hydrating the result documents. This makes queries faster and less memory intensive, but the result documents are plain JavaScript objects (POJOs), not Mongoose documents. In this tutorial, you'll learn more about the tradeoffs of using lean().

In my previous example the solution would be adding {lean: true}

```
db.Users.findOne(filter, projection, {lean: true}, (err, user)=>{
      let data = user.pendingFriendConfirmationData
      console.log(data)
    })
```

also here

```
db.Users.findOne(filter, projection, {lean: true}, (err, user)=>{
      let data = user.pendingFriendConfirmationData
      for(let i in data){
       if(data[i].choosenCategories.findIndex(v => v.value === "friends") !== -1){
        console.log("he is a friend")
      }
      }
    })

// he is a friend
```

**Conclusion**

to iterate over deeply nested subdocument array of objects you need to make sure 
that you are working with plain JavaScript objects (POJOs) using lean()

```
db.Users.find().lean()
```